# How to create an Amazon S3 job to move big files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to copy a file from one folder to another inside an unique Amazon S3 bucket. However, due to files size, I can't simply call copyObject method from AWS SDK S3 class, since it timesout my Lambda function.

That's why I'm trying to create a [S3 Batch Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops.html) job to move this file, but I'm getting an `Invalid job operation` error when trying to. I'm using AWS SDK `S3Control` class, trying to invoke method createJob. I'm passing this object as parameter:

```
{
    AccountId: '445084039568',
    Manifest: {
        Location: {
            ETag: 'dbe4a392892992491a7124c10f2fbf03',
            ObjectArn: 'arn:aws:s3:::amsp-media-bucket/manifest.csv'
        },
        Spec: {
            Format: 'S3BatchOperations_CSV_20180820',
            Fields: ['Bucket', 'Key']
        },
        
    },
    Operation: {
        S3PutObjectCopy: {
            TargetResource: 'arn:aws:s3:::amsp-media-bucket/bigtest'
        }
    },
    Report: {
        Enabled: false
    },
    Priority: 10, 
    RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::445084039568:role/mehoasumsp-sandbox-asumspS3JobRole-64XWYA3CFZF3'
}
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if I'm specifying manifest correctly. This is manifest.csv content:

```
amsp-media-bucket, temp/37766a92-16ef-4ee2-8e79-3875679dad85.mkv
```

I'm not insecure about the file itself but about the way I define Spec property at param object.

Comment: I believe you can move an object (changing its key) not necessarily creating a copy https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/mv.html

Comment: Which language are you using? I wonder if it is the space after the comma in the manifest file (unlikely)?

Comment: What size is the object?

Comment: gusto2: awscli `aws s3 mv` is implemented by copying the source and then deleting it. Changing the key of an S3 object is not possible.

Comment: I'm using node, and right now we are moving test files of about 2.5gs but our final goal is to be able to move files up to 100Gb

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes might not be valid in the job spec JSON. I have only seen double quotes.

In boto3 (Python SDK), using the managed .copy() function instead of .copy_object(), and tuning multipart_chunksize and the concurrency settings, the multiple UploadPartCopy requests may well complete within the Lambda runtime limit. The AWS JS SDK appears to lack an equivalent function, you may want to try something like https://github.com/Zooz/aws-s3-multipart-copy

As John Rotenstein said, beware the space in the object key in your CSV file.

S3PutObjectCopy S3 Batch Operation jobs use CopyObject, which has a size limit of 5GiB.

Together with the operation costs, S3 Batch Operation jobs cost $0.25 each, which might be expensive if copying a small number of objects.

Comment: Ok, so I checked this out, and it's not single quotes fault, and my csv does not actually have that space (that was my error when copying it). However, size limit and cost makes me think it might not be the solution I'm looking for. I'll look into multi part copying, to see if I can resolve it all inside a lambda. Thanks!